# determining the run time of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, runtime, big-o

I am trying to determine the runtime of this algorithm

[image: Algorithm]

I figure that the total runtime is O(n^2). Assuming that the array size is n, A.length is n, and the array is sorted in descending, then the outer loop runs from 2 to n, i.e. O(n-2)

The inner loop will be a sequential search as it goes through each element, so the runtime is O(n)

Total O(n^2)

Please clarify

Comment: You need to make difference between best and worst-case. In worst-case it's O(n^2) and in best case it's O(n)

Comment: So you're trying to determine the *runtime complexity*?

Comment: @JimMischel trying to determine runtime of the algo, but I see what you mean that its not the same as big-o, so how to determine the runtime for this algorithm?

Comment: No the "runtime" is the amount of clock time. You determine that by running the program and recording how much time it takes to complete. The *runtime complexity* is also referred to as "big-O," which is what it appears you're trying to determine.

Comment: Please clarify your terms first, runtime is runtime, complexity is complexity.